# Android - How can I make the whole page scroll if I have a listView inside?

Tags: android, android-layout

Right now I have this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >

<ScrollView
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent" >    

<LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >        
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/view_name"    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Business:"
    />         

<!--  
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/problem_name"    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Loading..."
    />
    -->       

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/business_privacy"    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Loading..."
    />    

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/learn"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop ="5dp"
    android:text="Learn About Business Topics Below"
    android:textColor="@color/light_best_blue"
    />    



    <ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+id/label"
        android:textSize="20px" >        


    </ListView>

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/extra_help"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop ="5dp"
    android:text="If You Need Help Planning"
    android:textColor="@color/light_best_blue"
    />             

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

But it shows a broken layout.

What I was trying to do is load the list of items with the ListView, and then add a button underneath that.

How could I accomplish that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't nest views which are scrollable in the same direction without weird stuff happening. However, you can add header and footer views to the listview, which should give the same effect.

Comment: footer idea is interesting, but I want to add something specific to this page only. Is there a way to change this layout so that it just shows the last button below the list?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The footer applies only to the listview which you set it on. Maybe if you do a diagram showing what you want scrollable, that might help. In general, if you want something to be shown inside the scrollable list at the top/bottom, footers are the way to go.